# Can I place a regulator in this way?

Tags: pcb-design, grounding

The regulator supports both digital circuits and analog circuits, which is shown in the diagram below.

[image: Regulator position]

My question is: can I place the regulator at the analog part? The regulator supplies the digital circuits with a thick trace. Usually, I put the regulator at the middle between digital circuits and analog circuits.

I think this way could be fine, since the return currents of MCU shall be low-frequency ones and shall go to Power In directly without going through the regulator.

Am I correct?

Comment: A good practice is to isolate the analog voltage with a ferrite bead and a few capacitors (e.g. 1uF and 0.1uF). As for the ground. Use a copper pour and connect both at single point close to the regulator.

Comment: Why is single point so important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's completely possible to run analog circuits from the same supply as digital circuits. There will be high frequency components noise on the Vdd **and the return** due to the switching. I don't know where you get the idea from that the supply current of the MCU will have only low frequency components.

If your requirements include very low noise or high performance analog circuitry, then you have to add another regulator, filtering or whatever is required to meet the system specifications.

It's not unusual for a switching regulator to have tens of mV noise on the output. Generally that's not a problem for digital circuits, but could be a complete non-starter with a sensitive analog front end. On the other hand, if your analog requirements are low frequency and 8-10 bits in accuracy, it may not be an issue.

Comment: 1. I think the MCU are will decoupled by small capacitors. And  a star power supply for MCU and analog circuits will be used. Would not that be sufficient? 2. Our SMPS has around 1mV noise vpp.

Comment: My question is actually can I place the regulator at the analog(left) part? Usually I would put it at the middle of analog circuits and digital circuits.

Comment: The ground is at least as important as the regulator output. If the current for the micro supply goes through a trace supplying analog circuitry then there will tend to be a bit more noise on it.

Comment: If a star connection is used and no overlap between the trace supplying analog circuits and the trace supplying digital circuits, then the only thing matters is the return currents. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, of course the digital circuit will influence the regulator output to one degree or another. The traces are not necessarily even the major part of the output impedance of the regulator- which could be several ohms at ~1MHz.